# How to convert a list of strings to a list of ints in Python 3x

Tags: python-3.x, string, list-comprehension

I'm trying to convert a list of numbers in string format to integers.

I've tried list comprehension: `marks = [int(x) for x in marks]` and I've also tried mapping: `new_list = list(map(int, marks))` but both of them lead to a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Full code:

```
size = int(input())
students_and_marks = []
students = []
marks = []

for x in range((size * 2)):
    students_and_marks.append(input())

for x in range(1):
    students.append(students_and_marks[0::2])
    marks.append(students_and_marks[1::2])

new_list = list(map(int, marks))
```

Comment: What is `marks`?

Comment: It doesn't sound like it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: `marks` is a list of numbers in string.  I've used `type(marks[x])` to confirm its data type.

Comment: The Python Interpreter is telling you that isn't the case. Both codes are correct though the first is the more "Pythonic" way. Side note, I would create a new variable for `marks` instead of reassigning.

Comment: I've posted the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your code samples are correct. If you want to apply a function to a list you can either use a list comprehension or a pass a map to the list constructor though the list comprehension is preferred.

The issue is with the input. Specifically,

```
marks.append(students_and_marks[1::2])
```

Consider,

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[1::2]
[2, 4]
```

From your question it's not clear what you intended to do with your slice i.e. `students_and_marks[1::2]`. You append it to `marks` even though `students_and_marks[1::2]` is already a list.

What you did was,

```
>>> marks = ['1', '2']
>>> nested_marks = []
>>> nested_marks.append(marks)
>>> nested_marks
[['10', '9']]
>>> int(nested_marks)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

While I believe you intended to do,

```
>>> students_and_marks = ['Linus', '10', 'David', '9']
>>> students = students_and_marks[::2]
>>> students
['Linus', 'David']
>>> marks = students_and_marks[1::2]
>>> marks
['10', '9']
>>> new_marks = [int(mark) for mark in marks]
>>> new_marks
[10, 9]
```

Comment: I had a big, mixed list of names and numbers.  It was in this format: `[name, its number, name, its number]`.

I wanted to create 2 lists.  1 for name and 1 for number and I wanted to keep the numbers at their indexes to correspond them with their assigned names.  But numbers were still string so I wanted to convert them into numbers/.

Comment: Why are you using `''.join()`?

Comment: Did you read my explanation and see my example? If the issue is you're getting a `TypeError`, do my code examples show why?

Comment: Not really.  I did read it but it doesn't make sense.  Sorry.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example related to your code. This seems like homework so I'm not going to outright tell you. I think it's worthwhile for you to see this bug.

Comment: its not homework lol its Hackerrank.  What I'm curious about is, why `''.join()` to turn them into a single string?  That's why it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Your question is `Why is this TypeError happening?`. It's because you're passing a list to the `int()` function.
I suggested to use `''.join` because that would solve your `TypeError`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190182/discussion-between-skam-and-andros-adrianopolos).

Answer (score 0):

Replace both `append()` method in 2nd loop with `extend()` and you are done.

> **Note:** The strategy that you are following is good if you are a beginner otherwise there exists best ways to do the same in a simple and with less code (time/space efficient).

Finally, your code will look like:

```
size = int(input())
students_and_marks = []
students = []
marks = []

for x in range((size * 2)):
    students_and_marks.append(input())

print(students_and_marks)
for x in range(1):
    students.extend(students_and_marks[0::2])
    marks.extend(students_and_marks[1::2])

print(marks)                     # ['R A', '2', 'K T', '4', 'P K', '6']
new_list = list(map(int, marks)) # ['2', '4', '6']
print(new_list)                  # [2, 4, 6]
```

> Terminal input & output

```
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:PythonCode hygull$ python3 stk_prob_str.py 
3
R A
2
K T
4
P K
6
['R A', '2', 'K T', '4', 'P K', '6']
['2', '4', '6']
[2, 4, 6]
```